# Clojure spec: how to validate either one or another map

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have this Clojure code to define my schema for reply objects, which can be either

`{:message {:text "Hello"} :delay 3000}`

or

`{:action "typing_on" :duration 5000}`

The `reply` map can either have `:message` or `:action` and respectively optional keys `:delay` and `:duration`.

I am trying to express it this way with `clojure.spec`:

```
(s/def ::action #{"typing_on" "typing_off" "mark_seen"})
(s/def ::duration int?)
(s/def ::delay int?)
(s/def ::message map?)

(s/def ::message-reply (s/keys :req-un [::message]
                               :opt-un [::delay]))

(s/def ::action-reply (s/keys :req-un [::action]
                              :opt-un [::duration]))

(s/def ::reply (or ::action-reply ::message-reply))
```

However, these specs will validate with `true` just the first schema they find within the `or` clause, in this case `::action-reply`.
What I am trying to achieve instead is that either `::action-reply` or `::message-reply` are valid schemas for `::reply`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you meant to use `s/or`, not `or` (which doesn’t really make sense in this context)?

```
(s/def ::reply (s/or :action-reply  ::action-reply
                     :message-reply ::message-reply))
```

Perhaps try `s/conform` on one of your values to see how you can use the conformed (‘spec-destructured’) value:

```
(s/conform ::reply {:message {:text "Hello"} :delay 3000})
; => [:message-reply {:message {:text "Hello"}, :delay 3000}]
```

Comment: I am still unsure why I need keys in the s/or clause, but this seems to correctly describe what I want.

Comment: @feychou The keys in the `s/or` clause allow you to see which branch was taken when data is conformed, or an error occurs